# why does the 'head' command read the string starting with '\0' correctly, with fgets doing wrong?

Tags: c, linux, shell, command, head

here the file I wanted to read out, with some unexpected '\0' inside

```
   1 
   2 Mon Aug 28 14:29:29 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 1 ont-info 
   3 Mon Aug 28 14:29:33 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 1 ont-unbound 
   4 Mon Aug 28 14:29:41 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
   5 Mon Aug 28 14:29:43 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
   6 Mon Aug 28 14:29:44 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
   7 Mon Aug 28 14:29:47 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
   8 Mon Aug 28 14:29:51 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
   9 Mon Aug 28 14:29:53 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
  10 Mon Aug 28 14:31:18 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
  11 Mon Aug 28 14:33:50 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: exi
  12 Mon Aug 28 14:33:51 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: exi
  13 Mon Aug 28 14:33:54 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: save config 
           14^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Mon Aug 28 14:37:00 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
  15 Mon Aug 28 14:37:01 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
  16 Mon Aug 28 14:37:03 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
  17 Mon Aug 28 14:37:07 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
  18 Mon Aug 28 14:37:21 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
  19 Mon Aug 28 14:37:22 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
  20 Mon Aug 28 14:37:27 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
```

here is my code with two ways to read it out to the shell, one using fgets(), and the other using linux 'head' cmd;

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <string.h>
  4 
  5 const int n = 20;
  6 
  7 #if 0
  8 int main(void)
  9 {
 10     FILE *fp = NULL;
 11     char line[1024];
 12     int i = 0;
 13 
 14     fp = fopen("/home/zyh/test/cli_log", "r");
 15     if (fp == NULL)
 16     {
 17         perror("failed to open cli_log\r\n");
 18         return -1;
 19     }
 20 
 21     while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
 22     {
 23         printf("%s", line);
 24         i++;
 25         if (i >= n)
 26             break;
 27     }
 28     fclose(fp);
 29 
 30     return 0;
 31 }
 32 #endif
 33 
 34 int main(void)
 35 {
 36     char cmd[50] = "head -n 20 /home/zyh/test/cli_log";
 37 
 38     system(cmd);
 39 
 40     return 0;
 41 }
```

and here are the results for two ways;

one with fgets

```
Mon Aug 28 14:29:29 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 1 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:33 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 1 ont-unbound 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:41 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:43 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:44 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:47 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:51 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:53 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:31:18 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:33:50 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: exi
Mon Aug 28 14:33:51 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: exi
Mon Aug 28 14:33:54 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: save config 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:01 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:03 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:07 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:21 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:22 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:27 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
```

one with head cmd

```
Mon Aug 28 14:29:29 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 1 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:33 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 1 ont-unbound 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:41 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:43 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:44 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:47 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:51 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:29:53 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:31:18 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: brief-show slot 2 ont-info 
Mon Aug 28 14:33:50 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: exi
Mon Aug 28 14:33:51 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: exi
Mon Aug 28 14:33:54 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:59927: save config 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:00 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:01 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:03 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:07 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:21 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:22 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot 
Mon Aug 28 14:37:27 2023 admin[::ffff:192.168.7.116]:60207: show slot
```

you can see the wrong line with time "14:37:00" gets printed out with head cmd, while with fgets doesn't;
So I'm confused about how head cmd prints out string staring with '\0'?

Is head cmd erase the all '\0',I try to push the output of head cmd into file,
`head -n 20 cli_log > head_log`,
but I open head_log, and find that it's same as cli_log.

Comment: For reading lines containing \0 it is preferable to use getline, which returns the number of bytes read. https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` is a `string` file function and `\0` has a very special meaning in C strings. That is the reason why it does not work as you think it should.

Do not string functions if your file is not properly formatted.

You need to treat this file as a binary file and read it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Your fgets-using program prints using the line
`printf("%s", line);`. Since `\0` is the string termination character in C strings, a line that starts with `\0` looks like an empty string to printf, and therefore it prints nothing. The unix `head` command, however, can deal with all bytes that might occur in a file, including a byte with a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` can read a *null character*, save it in its buffer and continue reading.  That is not the direct problem.

It is `printf("%s", line);` that is the issue as printing stops on the *first* null character in `line`, be it a null character read in by `fgets()` or the null character appended by `fgets()` when it was done.

Instead of `printf("%s", line);`, print the `n` characters read with `fwrite(line, 1, n, stdout)`.

With `fgets()`, finding the number of characters read `n` is problematic.

---

Alternative 1:

Read a *line* which might contain *null characters* and record the number of characters read.

Illustrative code (uncheck) which uses `"%4096[^\n]"` to read much of a line (not the `'\n'`) and `"%n"` to record the number of characters read.

```
char line[4096+1];
int len;
int conversion_cnt;
while (i < n && (conversion_cnt = fscanf(fp, "%4096[^\n]%n", line, &len)) != EOF) {
  if (conversion_cnt == 1) {
    fwrite(line, 1, len, stdout);
  } else {
    int ch = fgetc(fp);
    if (ch == EOF) {
      break;
    } 
    assert(ch == '\n');  // Only '\n' expected here.
    i++;
    fputc(ch, stdout);
  } 
}
```

---

Alternative 2:

Read blocks of data with `fread()` and stop once the 20th `'\n'` found.  Use `memchr()` or use a loop to  find the `'\n'`.

```
char block[4096];
size_t len;
while (i < n && (len = fread(block, 1, sizeof block, fp)) > 0) {
  for (size_t j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    if (block[j] == '\n') {
      i++;
      if (i >= n) {
        len = j + 1;
        break;
      } 
    }
  }   
  fwrite(line, 1, len, stdout);
}
```